# remove() method not working inside animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

In my webpage I have certain divs showing data of user. On a certain event I need to remove each div clicked. I thought to make it a little bit fancier before removing the div.
So I used animate method and inside callback of animate method I wrote the code to remove that div from dom. **But the problem is that it shows that remove cannot be called on null.** How is it that animate method ran on that div and inside its callback it became null.
Please help me in resolving the issue and also suggest if there is a better way to do it.

```
    confirmOpen = //Holding reference of div to be removed.
    //animate method is running perfectly fine.
    confirmOpen.animate({"width":"1px","height":"1px"},500,function()
    {
       console.log(confirmOpen); //Logging null
       confirmOpen.remove();   //Showing error that remove method cannot be called on a null value.
    });
```

Comment: can i have any jsfiddle reference ?

Comment: have you tried declaring confirmOpen like `var confirmOpen =`? You're using a global variable that you could be setting to null somewhere else?

Comment: you can use `(this).remove();`

Comment: [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/d4ajC/) works !!. check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4ajC/). you should put the  value that you are assigning to confirmOpen to get more clarity.

Comment: I just tested your code, and it was fine. My guess is that you are using this code in a closure. Stand alone, it works but putting it inside other code, there is no access to "confirmOpen". That is a guess, of course, without seeing all of the code. use $(this).remove();

Comment: put `console.log(confirmOpen)` before `animate()` function and say me is it null? if yes, your `confirmOpen` isn't properly defined.

Comment: Very sorry to waste ol of urs time.... I was setting the variable to null in the other method. So before the animation could end, it was being set to null. Damn u Monday morning..... Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some error while setting  the reference in the variable **confirmOpen**.
You can not remove a null value.

Comment: But he says he is able to animate it. How can that be possible?

Comment: Animate method is running perfectly.

Comment: try $(this).remove();

Comment: Very sorry to waste ol of urs time.... I was setting the variable to null in the other method. So before the animation could end, it was being set to null. Damn u Monday morning..... Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 0):

`confirmOpen` inside

```
confirmOpen.animate({"width":"1px","height":"1px"},500,function()
    {
```

will cause an error because there is no variable declartion inside that function and you are removing the same `confirmOpen` so you should use just `$(this).remove();`

Answer (score 0):

```
confirmOpen = //Holding reference of div to be removed.

    confirmOpen.animate({"width":"1px","height":"1px"},500,function()
    {
       console.log(confirmOpen);
       $(this).remove();   
    }); 


I hope it will work but can you send js fiddle example for more effective results
```